# Retornar datas existentes entre duas outras datas - Android

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma classe ou biblioteca que me retorne as datas existentes entre duas datas que eu passar.

Por exemplo: passaria as datas 23/02/2016 e 25/02/2016 e me retornaria a data 24/02/2016.

Vi muitos métodos ensinando a retornar a quantidade de datas existentes entre duas datas, não seria isso o que eu preciso, e imagino que criar uma classe para fazer isso que estou pedindo daria muito trabalho, então decidi arriscar para ver se alguém sabe se já existe algum método de se fazer isso.

Comment: Retornar aleatoriamente ou sempre será com essa diferença do exemplo?

Comment: Estas datas são em valor literal? **String** mesmo???

Comment: E se a entrada for 20/02/2016 e 25/02/2016 ?

Comment: As datas podem ser em qualquer valor no final posso converter para o que eu vou utilizar, no caso sendo String, o valor de retorno seria em ordem crescente das datas. No caso citado pelo Pablo ele retornaria: 21/02/2016, 22/02/2016, 23/02/2016 e 24/02/2016. O retorno pode também incluir as datas passadas no caso então ficaria: 20/02/2016, 21/02/2016, 22/02/2016, 23/02/2016, 24/02/2016 e 25/02/2016.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

**EDITADO**

Conforme o relato no comentário, há a necessidade de decrementar 1 no mês para setar uma Data (`String`) em um `Calendar`.

Exemplo:

```
final String[] valI = inicio.split("/");
cINI.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, Integer.valueOf(valI[0])-1);
```

Pensando nisto e afim de simplificar um pouco o código, segue o método modificado:

```
public static List<String> diferencaDeDatas(String inicio, String fim) throws ParseException{
    // Tranforma Date em String e vice-versa
    final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    // Clonamos os Calendar para não ter a mesma referencia
    Calendar cINI = (Calendar) c.clone();
    Calendar cFIM = (Calendar) c.clone();

    //Transformamos a STring em java.util.Date
    Date dtIni = sdf.parse(inicio);
    Date dtFim = sdf.parse(fim);

    // Setamos dos java.util.Date nos Calendar's 
    cINI.setTimeInMillis(dtIni.getTime());
    cFIM.setTimeInMillis(dtFim.getTime());

    // Se a data final for menor que a maior ou igual  retorna uma lista vazia...
    if(cFIM.getTimeInMillis() <= cINI.getTimeInMillis()){
        return new ArrayList<>(0);
    }
    // Lista que vamos retonar com o valores
    List<String> itens = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // adicionamos +1 dia, pois não iremos contar o dia inicial
    cINI.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cINI.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);

    // vamos realizar a acão enquanto a data inicial for menor q a final
    while(cINI.getTimeInMillis() < cFIM.getTimeInMillis()){
        // adicionamos na lista...
        itens.add(sdf.format(cINI.getTime()));
        // adicionamos +1 dia....
        cINI.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cINI.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+1);
    }

    return itens;
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado man

Comment: Opa, não percebi um pequeno problema com o seu código, quando você setar o mês da classe Calendar precisa deduzir 1 no valor do mês da String que foi passada, pois para o Calendar os meses começam em 0 e vão até 11, então do jeito que tá o código retorna as datas com um mês a mais do que as datas que você passou. Então as duas linhas do código ficariam:                                  cINI.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(valI[1]) - 1);                                        cFIM.set(Calendar.MONTH, Integer.valueOf(valI[1])- 1);